# Slide up/down effect with ng-show and ng-animate

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm trying to use `ng-animate` to get a behavior similar to JQuery's `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`. Only I'd rather use `ng-show`

I'm looking at the ng-animate tutorial here - http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html,

and I can reproduce the fade in/out effect in the example provided.

How could I change the css to get slide up/down behaviour?
Also, if possible, it's better that the css doesn't know about the component height in pixels.
That way I can reuse the css for different elements.

Comment: I do not think you will be able to get ng-show to handle animations. That is not its intended use. That is what ng-animate is for. Why do you want to use ng-show specifically?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I think you're mistaken. The given example does exactly that: a combination of ng-show and ng-animate (look for "Animating ngShow & ngHide"). Anyway, what I want is simply an effect to show/hide a div sliding up and down.

Comment: My mistake, I have not made use of ng-animate. It looks as though in they work in conjunction with each other.

Comment: You could try to use the `line-height` css attribute, from 0 to 100%. Sometimes it's works... Post your fiddle than we can help you better. If you find a good way to do this, please, send me it, to put this sample at my site: [AngularJS Ng-Animate](http://www.nganimate.org/)

Comment: Check this out http://www.nganimate.org/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I've written an Angular directive that does `slideToggle()` without jQuery.

https://github.com/EricWVGG/AngularSlideables

Comment: This looks exactly like what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: You say the directive is without jQuery, but methods `duration` `easing` `css` `bind` are jQuery one's, no ? (maybe i'm wrong)

Comment: @BastienSander Angular provides a subset of some of Jquery's methods if you don't include jquery before you include Angular, api docs for that here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

.css and .bind are provided there (which is used on the "element" variable).  The easing and duration properties aren't being used on element, so they're not referencing the Jquery methods of the same name, but are properties passed in on the HTML attributes (attrs object).

Comment: @JayKlehr: thanks for the answer, interesting to see.

Comment: Most minimal "accordion" style slider I have ever seen! Thank you! We modified it a little bit to remove IDs and class stuff that we saw as unnecessary as we could find the elements without IDs: http://plnkr.co/edit/11NIZqB3G3KYKI0OChGA?p=preview

Comment: The id's are kinda needed (if you want to dropdown an element that is somewhere else) so i made a slightly modification fixing some bugs and now it works like a charm.
http://plnkr.co/edit/XdRjap3TPFEC9180yq9k?p=preview

Comment: Ignore the plnkr comment ones, they offer nothing over Erics github version.  This  is very handy, thanks.

Comment: I know we've plunked this to death, but I like tying the visibility to variables. Also, this solution doesn't allow for embedded sliders. I've created a fiddle that does both: http://jsfiddle.net/rh7z7w0a/2/

Answer (score 40):

This is actually pretty easy to do. All you have to do is change the css.

Here's a fiddle with a very simple fade animation: http://jsfiddle.net/elthrasher/sNpjH/

To make it into a sliding animation, I first had to put my element in a box (that's the slide-container), then I added another element to replace the one that was leaving, just because I thought it would look nice. Take it out and the example will still work.

I changed the animation css from 'fade' to 'slide' but please note that these are the names I gave it. I could have written slide animation css named 'fade' or anything else for that matter.

The important part is what's in the css. Here's the original 'fade' css:

```
.fade-hide, .fade-show {
    -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}
.fade-hide {
    opacity:1;
}
.fade-hide.fade-hide-active {
    opacity:0;
}
.fade-show {
    opacity:0;
}
.fade-show.fade-show-active {
    opacity:1;
}
```

This code changes the opacity of the element from 0 (completely transparent) to 1 (completely opaque) and back again. The solution is to leave opacity alone and instead change the top (or left, if you want to move left-right).

```
.slide-hide, .slide-show {
    -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 1.5s;
}
.slide-hide {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
.slide-hide.slide-hide-active {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
}
.slide-show {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}
.slide-show.slide-show-active {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
}
```

I'm also changing from relative to absolute positioning so only one of the elements takes up space in the container at a time.

Here's the finished product: http://jsfiddle.net/elthrasher/Uz2Dk/. Hope this helps!

Comment: This was very helpful. I'm trying to figure out why the 'hide' transition is so sudden in your fiddle though, @elthrasher

Comment: @ericpeters0n - it's because of that 0.5s at the end of the transition line. That's the amount of time it'll take, half a second in this case. You may set that to whatever you like. Try 5s or 10s.

Comment: The behavior is kind of odd. Sometimes the text appears from the top and sometimes from the bottom.

Comment: I know it's an old answer but if anybody wants to give this a try I'd like to clarify that using `ng-hide="hidden == false"` is redundant, if the `hidden` variable is already a boolean then the operator is not needed at all.

Answer (score 17):

update for **Angular 1.2+** (v1.2.6 at the time of this post):

```
.stuff-to-show {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: top linear 1.5s;
  transition: top linear 1.5s;
  top: 0;
}
.stuff-to-show.ng-hide {
  top: -100px;
}
.stuff-to-show.ng-hide-add,
.stuff-to-show.ng-hide-remove {
  display: block!important;
}
```

([plunker](http://plnkr.co/buPkXh))

Comment: Don't animate top position with css, it is very slow and takes up a lot of memory. Use translate instead.

Comment: Also works on Angular 1.4. Tested and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 16):

This can *actually* be done in CSS and very minimal JS just by adding a CSS class (don't set styles directly in JS!) with e.g. a `ng-click`event. The principle is that one can't animate `height: 0;` to `height: auto;` but this can be tricked by animating the `max-height` property. The container will expand to it's "auto-height" value when `.foo-open` is set - no need for fixed height or positioning.

```
.foo {
    max-height: 0;
}

.foo--open {
    max-height: 1000px; /* some arbitrary big value */
    transition: ...
}
```

see [this fiddle by the excellent Lea Verou](http://jsfiddle.net/zwvNY/3347/)

As a concern raised in the comments, note that while this animation works perfectly with linear easing, any exponential easing will produce a behaviour different from what could be expected - due to the fact that the animated property is `max-height` and not `height` itself; specifically, only the `height` fraction of the easing curve of `max-height` will be displayed.

Comment: That's bad cause the animation speed changes depending on `max-height`.

Comment: why is it *bad*? If you are having issues with the animation speed, simply set the transition duration to a reasonable value based on your `max-height`. It's exactly how transitions are supposed to work.

This method actually has the benefit that the slideup/down speed remains constant regardless of the `height`

Comment: It works well only with linear easing. With all other easings you only get the `height/maxHeight` part of the curve. The experience is bad.

Comment: I've added my answer to prove the point that it can this can be achieved with pure css (no js) and without fixing or worrying about the height of the element. As per the OP question: "it's better that the css doesn't know about the component height in pixels" - he's not asking about easing here. I'm not taking it personally of course, but while your point is technically correct about other easing types, I don't really think my answer is so 'bad' or 'wrong' to be downvoted.

Comment: Well, while I started researching this I got the impression that this solution is a silver bullet so if worded differently (by including the downsides) I would change my vote. Note that `slideUp` and `slideDown` in the question are usually done with some easing.

Comment: @RushPL this is a fair explanation - it makes sense now.

Comment: I have to vote on this approach. Simple, as well as using ngAnimate framework.

Comment: If you change the text color to black on the fiddle, you will see that it doesn't actually hide the contents. You just couldn't see it until you hovered because the text was white.

Comment: @MarcieKaiser `overflow: hidden;` fixes it - see the updated link

Comment: This should be marked the answer as I was lead here in search of a way to cheat height:auto like the original poster was

Comment: This solution can cause issues when the content is larger than allowed by the `max-height`. In such a case the bottom of the content would be cut off by `overflow: hidden`. Increasing the `max-height` isn't a great solution because when the content is much smaller the animation is very abrupt. For example, if animating to a max-height of 2000px but the height of the div is 200px it'll complete the animation within 1/10th the time.

Comment: @Hirshy this is true, afaik there is no bulletproof solution in CSS however it does work fine in certain contexts (and we don't know in what one the OP will be using this)

Answer (score 8):

I ended up abandoning the code for my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31524171/404699) to this question and going with this answer instead.

I believe the best way to do this is to not use `ng-show` and `ng-animate` at all.

```
/* Executes jQuery slideDown and slideUp based on value of toggle-slidedown 
   attribute.  Set duration using slidedown-duration attribute.  Add the 
   toggle-required attribute to all contained form controls which are
   input, select, or textarea.  Defaults to hidden (up) if not specified
   in slidedown-init attribute.  */
fboApp.directive('toggleSlidedown', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if ('down' == attrs.slidedownInit){
                elem.css('display', '');
            } else {
                elem.css('display', 'none');
            }
            scope.$watch(attrs.toggleSlidedown, function (val) {
                var duration = _.isUndefined(attrs.slidedownDuration) ? 150 : attrs.slidedownDuration;
                if (val) {
                    elem.slideDown(duration);
                } else {
                    elem.slideUp(duration);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the newer solution. Out of curiosity (as I didn't find any particular issues with piggybacking off ng-hide/ng-show) ... what was the problem with that approach?

Comment: You should have modified your previous answer instead of creating a new one (imagine the mess if everybody creates a new answer each time they want to modify something...)

Comment: @tanguy_k I think there might be a way to correct the first answer, and possibly both approaches are valid.  I guess I was hoping someone would critique my first answer and tell me why it occasionally fails.  I think there may be multiple equally good answers to this question.

Comment: Problem with editing the original answer is that if the questioner marked that as 'correct' and then you make significant mods... that seems like a bad idea as well.

Answer (score 6):

This class-based javascript animation works in AngularJS 1.2 (and 1.4 tested)

**Edit**:  I ended up abandoning this code and went a completely different direction. I like [my other answer much better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32126359/404699). This answer will give you some problems in certain situations.

```
myApp.animation('.ng-show-toggle-slidedown', function(){
  return {
    beforeAddClass : function(element, className, done){
        if (className == 'ng-hide'){
            $(element).slideUp({duration: 400}, done);
        } else {done();}
    },
    beforeRemoveClass :  function(element, className, done){
        if (className == 'ng-hide'){
            $(element).css({display:'none'});
            $(element).slideDown({duration: 400}, done);
        } else {done();}
    }
}
```

});

Simply add the `.ng-hide-toggle-slidedown` class to the container element, and the jQuery slide down behavior will be implemented based on the ng-hide class.

You must include the `$(element).css({display:'none'})` line in the `beforeRemoveClass` method because jQuery will not execute a slideDown unless the element is in a state of `display: none` prior to starting the jQuery animation.  AngularJS uses the CSS

```
.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

to hide the element.  jQuery is not aware of this state, and jQuery will need the `display:none` prior to the first slide down animation.

The AngularJS animation will add the `.ng-hide-animate` and `.ng-animate` classes while the animation is occuring.

Comment: This works perfectly for me while I wasn't able to get the other answers to work well for me. Up-voted!

Comment: @zaichang I ended up abandoning this code and went a completely different direction.  I like my [other answer much better](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32126359/404699).  This answer will give you some problems in certain situations.

Comment: @steampowered This will/can not work with `ngIf`. But I see too that it is not working in some occasions even when you use `ngShow`. E.g. it seems that it doesn't work when I use it inside a modal created with UI-Bootstrap. This is weird. When did it fail for you?

Comment: the display:none thing did the trick... using ng-animate/ng-show with enter/leave functions and jquery UI toggle effects. Nothign worked right until I added display:none to the element... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should use Javascript animations for this - it is not possible in pure CSS, because you can't know the height of any element. Follow the instructions it has for you about javascript animation implementation, and copy slideUp and slideDown from jQuery's source.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with actually using `ng-animate` for `ng-show` as you mentioned?

```
<script src="lib/angulr.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angulr_animate.js"></script>
<script>
    var app=angular.module('ang_app', ['ngAnimate']);
    app.controller('ang_control01_main', function($scope) {

    });
</script>
<style>
    #myDiv {
        transition: .5s;
        background-color: lightblue;
        height: 100px;
    }
    #myDiv.ng-hide {
        height: 0;
    }
</style>
<body ng-app="ang_app" ng-controller="ang_control01_main">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck">
    <div id="myDiv" ng-show="myCheck"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: It works if you can hard code the height in your CSS, but that is often not possible.