# How can show specific number of li using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to show 3 `li` and after 1 second these 3 `li` will be slide up and next 3 `li` will be automatically show up in the `div.#content`

```
<div id="content">
    <ul>
        <li>122</li>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>second</li>
        <li>third</li>
        <li>fourth</li>
        <li>fifth</li>
        <li>sixth</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have done this thing using jquery but i need to developed using angularJs and i'm not expert in angularjs. [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/t5qbbhv2/2/) you can see already done using jquery. I will appreciate if some guide me.

Comment: you can try $interval which is Angular's wrapper for window.setInterval. See the official documnetation.

Comment: [This answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19735977/5520354) has a directive that implements .slideUp/Down without in Angular without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just translation, then run the snippet

```js
(function ()
{
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    function HomeController($interval)
    {
        var vm = this;        
        var i = 2,
            $ul = angular.element('#content ul');
        int = $interval(function ()
            {
                angular.element('li', $ul).slideUp();
                angular.element('li' + (i == -1 ? '' : ':gt(' + i + ')') + ':lt(3)', $ul).slideDown();
                i += 3;
                if (i + 1 >= angular.element('li', $ul).length) i = -1;
            },
            2000);
    }

    app.controller("HomeController", ["$interval",HomeController]);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular JS App</title>        
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container" ng-controller="HomeController as homeCtrl">


            <div id="content">
                <ul>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                    <li>4</li>
                    <li>5</li>
                    <li>6</li>
                    <li>7</li>
                    <li>8</li>
                    <li>9</li>
                </ul>
            </div>           

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge its working but can we remove jquery because i don't want to use jquery.

Comment: The problem is that slideUp() and slideDown() are from jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MDhMKXVDwKaXZPvksY6f?p=preview). I have removed jQuery but have used some math logic.

```
var i = 0;

    var mainList=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    $scope.list = [mainList[i],mainList[i+1],mainList[i+2]];

    $ul = angular.element('#content ul');

    int = $interval(function ()
        {
             if(i>8){
              i=0;
            }
            $scope.list=[mainList[i],mainList[i+1],mainList[i+2]];
        },
        2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```js
angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('slideRoller',function($interval){
        return {
            restrict:'A',
            link:function(scope,ele,attrs){
                var interval = attrs.interval || 2000;
                var children = ele.find('li');

                var start = -1;
                roll(start);
                $interval(function(){
                    start += 3;
                    if(start>=children.length-3){
                        start = -1;
                    }
                    roll(start);
                },interval);

                function roll(i){
                    angular.forEach(children,function(val,index){
                        if(index>i && index<=i+3){
                            angular.element(val).removeClass('slide-up').addClass('slide-down');
                        }else{
                            angular.element(val).removeClass('slide-down').addClass('slide-up');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    })
;
```

```css
.slide-up{
 max-height: 0;
 overflow-y: hidden;
}

.slide-down {
 max-height: 10em;
 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
 transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Single Demo</title>
    <script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <div class="container">
        <ul slide-roller interval="1000">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer, just an information for you

If you import `jQuery`, `AngularJs` implements it so it's not really wrong to use `jQuery`.

Instead, if you don't want import `jQuery`, `AngularJs` falls back to `jQlite` (really similar to `jQuery`)

From the official documentation:

> Does Angular use the jQuery library?
>   Yes, Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call jQLite.
>
> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

FAQ page: https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

Angular jqLite: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Can we use both Jquery and angularjs for web ?

Comment: @ayazkhan yes... The coding style will be different though.

Comment: you can, you can use angular to do the slide effect, just instead of ```jQuery(...).slideUp()``` you'll use ```angular.element(...).slideUp()```, because angular will import the slideUp method from jQuery (it work only if you import jquery or this method exists on jqLite)